# Nginx rewrite by directory

Tags: nginx

Trying to redirect a file in Nginx.conf but unsuccessful. I want to redirect from the directory

> /data/file/static/sites/index.html

to

> /data/file/static/sites/desktop/index.html

My nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name test.com;
    root    /data/file/static/sites;

  location /data/file/static/sites/index.html {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /data/file/static/sites/desktop/index.html break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
location /index.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /desktop/index.html break;
}
```

since you have `root    /data/file/static/sites;`, you don't need the full path in location.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rewrite ^/index.html$ /desktop/index.html redirect;
```